# Booting Into Fresh Install of Ubuntu on Lenovo x120e

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Finished installing Ubuntu, in what appears to be a successful installation. However, I cannot boot into it ("No Operating System Found"). After researching, I came across [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X120e) that advises the following steps:

> 1. set BIOS to allow non-EFI boot
> 2. boot to Live CD
> 3. make directiry /mnt/1 , mount installed partition to /mnt/1
> 4. mount --bind /dev /mnt/1/dev ,same to /proc, /sys
> 5. chroot /mnt/1
> 6. aptitude update; aptitude purge grub-efi ; aptitude install grub-pc

Was able to create the `/mnt/1/` directory, but not familiar with the "mounting procedures" described in steps 3,4,5,6. Can someone walk me through these bits?

Comment: That procedure will set Ubuntu to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, which might work well for you or it might just be digging yourself in deeper. Are you currently dual-booting with Windows or some other OS? If so, you should coordinate your boot modes (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI). Posting a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file generated by the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) would give the information necessary to give a better response.

Comment: Not dual booting with Windows. I just want one OS (Ubuntu Linux). Have already installed Ubuntu, just can't boot into it ("Operating System Not Found"). In the process of generating the results file. Going to take a few minutes as I have to boot into the "Live CD" ...

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how do I, from Terminal, perform the following: "mount installed partition to /mnt/1" ?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up installing an older version of Ubuntu `10.04.4 LTS - Lucid Lynx`; after first disabling `UEFI` in the `BIOS`. Then, installed the latest Ubuntu `14.04.2 LTS - Trusty Tahr` over it. This remedied the boot issue and am now able to boot into Ubuntu on my `X120e`.